# Property 'enableLicensing' not valid in version 44.0

Tags: api

Having an issue that's driving me a little nuts. Every time I go to deploy any objects from IntelliJ into either a sandbox or production environment, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR deploying CustomObject <object name>: Property 'enableLicensing' not valid in version 44.0
```

Our sandboxes and production environment are API version 45, and I am running IntelliJ / Illuminated Cloud in API version 45 as well. In order to get around this error, I am having to remove the `<enableLicensing>false</enableLicensing>` tag from each object I'm attempting to deploy.

Hoping someone has some insight into how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the `version` tag in the `package.xml` manifest you're using for the project to `45.0`:

```
<version>45.0</version>
```

It sounds like your metadata's being pulled over API 45.0 but deployed via 44.0.

Comment: Of COURSE it's in the package.xml, the one spot I didn't check. This fixed the issue right up.